# Cors request working in Excel but not in Javascript

Tags: javascript, excel, cors, vba

I understand the CORS policy and since the server is not set to accept CORS requests, I should not be able to download the CSV file from a different origin. However the server seems perfectly happy to fullfill the request when it is made from VBA in Excel. So why can't I grab the same file using Javascript?

In Excel:

```
Sub transfercsv()
sCSVLink = "https://subdomain.domain.com/specific_page/pending_csv?var=specificLocation"
sfile = "Filename_Specific_Location_" & Year(Date) & "-" & Month(Date) & "-" & Day(Date) & ".csv"
ssheet = "CSV Transfer"
Set wnd = ActiveWindow
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets(ssheet).Cells.ClearContents
Workbooks.Open Filename:=sCSVLink
Windows("pending_CSV").Activate
ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy
wnd.Activate
Sheet1.Select
Sheets("CSV Transfer").Range("A1").Select
Sheets("CSV Transfer").Paste
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Windows("pending_CSV").Activate
Windows("pending_CSV").Close False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Call anotherFunc
End Sub
```

In Javascript:

```
function displayData(){
    //this function takes a csv and displays it as a table in the page
  var tabulate = function (data,columns) {
      var table = d3.select('body').append('table')
        var thead = table.append('thead')
        var tbody = table.append('tbody')
        thead.append('tr')
          .selectAll('th')
            .data(columns)
            .enter()
          .append('th')
            .text(function (d) { return d })
        var rows = tbody.selectAll('tr')
            .data(data)
            .enter()
          .append('tr')
        var cells = rows.selectAll('td')
            .data(function(row) {
                return columns.map(function (column) {
                    return { column: column, value: row[column] }
              })
          })
          .enter()
        .append('td')
          .text(function (d) { return d.value })
      return table;
    }
    //this function actually makes the xhr request and gets the csv
    d3.csv('https://subdomain.domain.com/specific_page/pending_csv?var=specificLocation',function (data) {
        var columns = ['column_name_1','column_name_2','column_name_3','column_name_4','column_name_5','column_name_6','column_name_7','column_name_8','column_name_9','column_name_10','column_name_11']
      tabulate(data,columns)
    })
```

So the Excel code above works for me no problem, but the Javascript code above gives me a security error:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://subdomain.domain.com/specific_page/pending_csv?var=specificLocation. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

Also, I have no control over the server. That app is controlled by a different team at my company(In a different location) I am surprised that CORS is in effect because my domain is: mydomain.somebs.domain.com Theirs is: theirdomain.domain.com So I can't just accept my subdomain in their server policy.

So there should be a way for me to get this resource with Javascript right?

Comment: Do you have control over the server? In order to allow CORS requests, you need to have the server return an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header with your domain (or `*`) as the value, just as the error you receive indicates.

Comment: I guess I should have been more specific. I have no control over the server. That app is controlled by a different team at my company(In a different location) I am surprised that CORS is in effect because my domain is:
mydomain.somebs.domain.com
Theirs is: theirdomain.domain.com
So I can't just accept my subdomain in their server policy.
Updating the initial post.

Comment: Since the server's returning a csv, jsonp isn't an option - I believe the cleanest option would be to contact the team responsible for the server and have them add the CORS header and specify the base domain: `Access-control-allow-origin: https://domain.com`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because CORS is typically a browser policy, Excel doesn't care about CORS policy because Excel isn't really vulnerable to a scenario that browsers face every day (fake websites running javascript that pulls data from the real site.) If what you're doing is just a one off scenario you can disable CORS policy in your browser, but that won't work for a production website.

My advice would be to use some php in a server side script to download the CSV and then print its contents..

Something like...

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents('http://otherdomain.com/that_csv_file.csv');
?>
```

Then point your javascript url at your now 'same domain' php script.

Comment: Thanks for your quick suggestion.This was the working response. It makes no sense to me though that you can't grab a resource from the client side with ajax and fiddle with it but you can grab it from the server side and pump the data into javascript and fiddle with it... I'll have to read more into what CORS is supposed to prevent.