# XMLHttpRequest, working in Excel VBA, not working in javascript/html

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, vba, request

I'm trying to get opendata from a website in to my own website. I'm using this code (got it from  a w3schools example) and tried to combine that with my working code in Excel/VBA. 
But somehow I can't get it to work on my website... what am I missing in my html/javascript?

HTML: https://codepen.io/1234cb/pen/ZEEqxJK

```
<body>
<h1>XMLHttpRequest</h1>
<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Request data</button>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState > 1) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
            this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("POST", "https://www.energielabel.nl/api/v1/checkenergylabel", false);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)");
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
  xhttp.send("Postcode=2651ES&HouseNr=109&HouseNrAddition=");

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

VBA:

```
Sub getopendata()
Set ObjHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
URL = "https://www.energielabel.nl/api/v1/checkenergylabel"
ObjHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
ObjHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
ObjHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
ObjHTTP.setRequestHeader "Connection", "Keep-Alive"
ObjHTTP.send ("Postcode=2651es&HouseNr=109")
ActiveCell = ObjHTTP.responsetext
Set ObjHTTP = Nothing
Set xmlDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you have

```
xhttp.send("Postcode=2651ES&HouseNr=109&HouseNrAddition=");

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
```

You have to remove this line: `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;` because you already handle responseText within `onreadystatechange` callback.

Comment: Tnx Andrew! tried to remove that line, doesn't seem to have any effect..

Comment: I've tried your code without that line, it works. Does your code work, too? If so, please accept my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, but if i try this in [link]https://codepen.io/1234cb/pen/ZEEqxJK i see no results

Comment: Please check your JS console, errors and warnings are logged there. Also, CORS requests are not allowed on codepen.

Comment: codepen could be a problem. Chrome mentions CORS-problem: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. And: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 415 (Unsupported Media Type). Happens also in EDGE. In IE  no problems at all, perfectly showing the results.

Comment: could this be why excel works and modern browsers do not: [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41467992/cors-request-working-in-excel-but-not-in-javascript/41468150[link]

Comment: You said, literally: "trying to get opendata from a website in to my own website". So please check the JS console on your website and look for errors/warnings. Excel is off-topic here. If that site energielabel.nl sends you a CORS header then you can get a full response, problem solved. Otherwise your code will never work.

Comment: When i place this code on my webserver and open the page in Chrome or EDGE, it shows the error for 'CORS' and 'Unsupported Media Type'. So, if i understand you correctly, without  correct CORS-header my html will never work. Would it work if i embed excel in my website?

Comment: Actually, I never tried to embed an excel sheet in a website. A solution could be retrieve that page through a server-side script, parse it and send results to the client.

Comment: Well, I just read that excel-macro's won't work online. The latter option is out of my league